# Swift 4 rotate only one screen of UITabBarController

Tags: swift

I have a UITabBarController class and want only one of the ViewControllers to rotate, all other ViewControllers should always be displayed in portrait mode.

When switching from RotateViewController to another ViewController in landscape, the screen will remain in landscape regardless of the rotation. It looks like the correct rotation is not "reassessed" when switching screens.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    if self.selectedViewController is RotateViewController {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if self.selectedViewController is RotateViewController {
        return [.portrait, .landscapeRight, .landscapeLeft]
    }
    return .portrait
}
```

Forcing rotation does not work. This will render all separate elements in landscape and then rotate the entire screen.

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
```

Answer (score 0):

In **AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController) {
        if (rootViewController.responds(to: Selector(("canRotate")))) {
            return .allButUpsideDown;
        }
    }

    return .portrait;
}

private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
    if (rootViewController == nil) { return nil }
    if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
}
```

In your **ViewController** add

```
override func viewDidLoad {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.canRotate()
}

@objc func canRotate() -> Void {}
```

Comment: Hi A.K.M., thanks for your answer. This gives the same result as described above. If the phone is in landscape mode and the user switched to a different screen, it will remain in landscape mode until the user turns the phone upright. I want it to change to portrait mode regardless of what the user does.

Comment: Change return .allButUpsideDown; whatever you want

Comment: Hi A.K.M., .allButUpsideDown IS what I want. This however doesn't solve my problem that if the view if in landscape mode, it will take that landscape mode to any other view until you tilt your phone and it "locks" in portrait mode